# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Every time I try to run the code below I get the error that is in the title, how do I fix this?

```
#include <SDL\SDL.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you lind the SDL library? check [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post more details about the os/compiler/lnker/libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the linker is unable to find the function SDL_Init. This is usually caused by improper paths to the libraries that contain function definition.

In our case :

You can either put all required SDL dlls into your Output directory(by default it will be the bin folder)

Or

1. Goto Project properties
2. In **Linker -> Input** and and specify the SDL dlls
3. In **Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories** specify the path to the SDL dlls

Comment: I fixed it, i used the x32 instead of the x64 one that i was using previously and this fixed it, even though i'm on a 64 bit machine, thanks anyways !

Comment: Oh in that case the SDL libraries you are using must be 32 bit. You cannot link a 32 bit dll with 64-bit application. The architecture should match.